# How to mock variables in the initializer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
Class Client 
def initialize(options = {})
      @key = options['oauth_key']
      @secret = options['oauth_secret']
      @access_token_url = options['oauth_access_token_url']
      @signature_method = options['signature_method']
      @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@key, @secret, {access_token_url: @access_token_url, signature_method: @signature_method})
    end
```

How can i mock all these using mocha in rails(mainly the consumer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oauth_mock = mock('oauth')
OAuth::Consumer.stubs(:new).returns(oauth_mock)
```